# How to print in Grayscale from 'Preview' on MAC OSX?

Tags: macos, printing, preview.app

I can't for my life figure this out?! The accepted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/236727/how-can-i-print-in-grayscale-low-quality-from-preview) isn't helping me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it! It was hidden in the depths of Preview printing options. Select Paper Type/Quality and it's under 'Color Options':

[image]

---

<sub>EDIT - Cullub</sub>

**In OSX 10.10.3, Preview**

Under `Quality & Media`.

[image: OSX 10.10.3]

Comment: In Yosemite, I found it in *Imaging* rather than *Paper Type/Quality*.

Comment: ... And I found it in *Quality & Media* - A Check box at the bottom.

Comment: In El Capitan, I found it in _Image Options > Output Color > Black and White_. I'm glad OS X makes this consistent.

Comment: I also have El Capitan and the only menu options I have are "preview", "layout", "color matching", "paper handling", "paper feed", "cover page" and  "supply levels". "Color matching" appears to be about encoding? None of the above have a grayscale checkbox. Could this be printer specific?

Comment: High Siera try  Preview > Print dialog > color settings > none.  You need to change it every time you print.  fyi: I'm able to greyscale print from Acrobat Reader DC to same printer

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling the cause of the variety of locations is due to the printer drivers themselves.

The drivers are provided by the manufacturers, even the ones included with the OS. I don't think they all follow the same human interface guidelines or don't make much of an attempt at uniformity.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who don't have the "Grayscale printing" option available on Canon printer: You can set this in "Canon IJ Printer Utility" app. You should be able to find it with Spotlight.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an Epson printer on a Mac and the grayscale printing option does not show up in the preview app when the file is a jpeg, png, or other image.

When I convert the image to PDF, that option appears.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1193345)